# MSBuild not detected

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I want to build Apache cordova(6.1.1) project in visual studio 2015, when I build the project in simulator it always showing the below errors:

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
Error: No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target.

is there any solution I am using windows 10,64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of that, by adding c:\windows\system (64bit)  or system32 (32bit.) to my PATH environment.